# AJAX jquery value autoincrement

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to pass in data a value that autoincrement everytime I call this function but in this example limit always has value 3

```
var limit=0;
$.ajax({
     type: "post",
     url: "from.php",
     data: "limit="+3,
     success: function(data) {}
});
```

Comment: How do you expect it to be updated like that? You are not adding `3` to the variable `limit`.

Comment: I just wanted to arrange text here ; in my code there is no $nbsp;

Comment: Place the autoincrement value in input type hidden and get the value from input when you are calling this function again

Comment: Did you mean  `data: "limit+="3,`??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is what you need:

```
    var limit=0;
    $.ajax({
         type: "post",
         url: "from.php",
         data: {"limit":limit},
         success: function(data) {
limit = limit + 1;
}
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this -

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "from.php",
    data: {limit: ++limit},
    success: function(data) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I your ajax, you are just concatenating the string `"limit="+3`, which do not increment the value of limit variable.

You have to change the value of limit variable first.

```
limit +=3
```

And then can pass the value in ajax

```
data: "limit="+limit,
```

Hope it helps.